# Library not found with fortran

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to compile a file using fortran and nag fortran library
on a 32x machine works perfectly
but doesn't work on a 64x one
however the same program works on other 64x machines

everytime there is a message error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnag`

how can i solve this?

i'm adding some info about my problem

so this kind of additional error message

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libnag.a when searching for -lnag
```

comes when i compile using

```
f77 d01dafe.f -lnag
```

but when compiling with

```
f77 d01dafe.f -L/usr/lib/libnag.a
```

i get

```
d01dafe.o: in function « MAIN__ »:
fort77-2895-1.c:(.text+0xda): undefined reference to « d01daf_ »
fort77-2895-1.c:(.text+0x209): undefined reference to « d01daf_ »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: for the compiling part i use
f77 d01dafe.f -lnag

Comment: Why don't you just send an email to support@nag.co.uk?

Comment: they did'nt answer yet

Answer (score 1):

The Users' Note (un.html) for your NAG Library gives details about how to access the Library. This file should have been installed (somewhere!) when your Library was installed. Notes for Marks 22, 23 and 24 are also available at http://www.nag.co.uk/numeric/fl/FLinuns.asp.

For example, from http://www.nag.co.uk/doc/inun/fl24/l6adfl/un.html#accessing
(for the `gfortran` Library)

"
To use the NAG Fortran Library and the supplied ACML libraries, you may link in the following manner:

```
gfortran -I[INSTALL_DIR]/nag_interface_blocks driver.f90 [INSTALL_DIR]/lib/libnag_acml.a [INSTALL_DIR]/acml/libacml_mp.a -lgomp
```

where driver.f90 is your application program;

or

```
gfortran -I[INSTALL_DIR]/nag_interface_blocks driver.f90 [INSTALL_DIR]/lib/libnag_acml.so [INSTALL_DIR]/acml/libacml_mp.so
```

if the shareable library is required. Please note that the shareable library is fully resolved so that you need not link against other run-time libraries explicitly; this requires the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to be set correctly at link time (see below).

However, if you prefer to link to a version of the NAG Library which does not require the use of ACML you may wish to use the self-contained libraries as follows:

```
gfortran -I[INSTALL_DIR]/nag_interface_blocks driver.f90 [INSTALL_DIR]/lib/libnag_nag.a
```

or

```
gfortran -I[INSTALL_DIR]/nag_interface_blocks driver.f90 [INSTALL_DIR]/lib/libnag_nag.so
```

if the shareable library is required.
"

Note in particular that there is no `libnag.a` or `libnag.so`, so that just using `-lnag` will never work anyway. For access to the no-vendor Library (assuming your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set correctly) you should probably be doing something like

```
f77 d01dafe.r -lnag_nag
```

Comment: actually the nag library i have is the fllux19dg one it's a Mark 19.
There is a libnag.a file and in the installation note it shoud be copied to /usr/lib or some other directory
i did that on my x32 ubuntu , worked from the beginning with the 
' f77 d01dafe.f -lnag'
 or 
' f77 d01dafe.f -L/usr/lib/libnag.a'

on the x64 ubuntu, it doesn't work

Comment: You are seeing the message `/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible .../libnag.a when searching for -lnag`. Because you are using a 32-bit NAG Library, on a 64-bit system you will need to tell the compiler to generate code for a 32-bit environment: e.g., `f77 -m32 a00aafe.f -L/usr/lib/fllux20dgn -lnag` works for an FL20 Library I have.

Comment: I used that too but it doesn't work, i get the same error message.